# Slug Issue In Deploying Flask App to Heroku

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, heroku, nltk

I am currently trying to deploy a Flask application to Heroku but I keep on encountering this error
Compiled slug size: 2.3G is too large (max is 500M. I thinking it is from a model that I am importing in my code `model = SentenceTransformer('distilbert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')` but I dont know how to fix it.

I have tried using lighterweight models but I still keep on encountering the same error.

Comment: 2.3G is _way_ above Heroku's slug size limit. I'm not familiar with that library, but lots of ML / NLP libraries include huge amounts of data. Assuming that's the case here, Heroku might not be the best fit for your application.